# query based on languange one to many relation entity framewok

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to query translation based on langunage name, Below is my ef scheme

```
 public class Noun
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TranslationNoun> Translations { get; set; }
}
public class TranslationNoun
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LangungeId")]
    public Langunge Langunge { get; set; }
    public int NounId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("NounId")]
    public Noun Noun { get; set; }
}
public class Langunge
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So here is sample data

**Language**: Id=1,Name = English

**Language**: Id=2,Name = Franche

**Language**: Id=3,Name = Indonesia

**Noun**: id=1,Name="Makan";

**TranslationNoun** : id=1, Content=Eat, LanguageId=1,NounId=1

**TranslationNoun** : id=2, Content=Le menger, LanguageId=2,NounId=1

**TranslationNoun** : id=3, Content=Mangan, LanguageId=3,NounId=1

I want to focus on Noun table, how do i query and show Noun Translation Based on Languange Name:

Example When user choose English Language then it will return

**Noun** 1,Makan,Eat

When user choose Indonesia Language then it will return

**Noun** 1,Makan,Mangan

When user choose Francje Language then it will return

**Noun** 1,Makan,Le menger

Thanks for your nice attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
  var result =  _dbContext.TranslationNoun.Include(x => x.Noun).Include(x => x.Language)
                                    .Where(x => x.Language.Id == @langParamId)
                                    .Select(x=>new { x.Noun.Id, x.Noun.Name, x.Content});
```

---

Or If you want to filter based on Language Name then you can use

```
.Where(x => x.Language.Name == "@langParamName")
```

Comment: it seems you query from TranslationNoun table, is it  possible to query from dbContext.Noun

Comment: You can try like : `_dbContext.Noun.Include(x => x.TranslationNoun).Where(x => x.TranslationNoun.Language.Id == @langParamId).Select(x=>new { x.Id, x.Name, x.TranslationNoun.Content});`